# split method doesn't recognise String

Tags: javascript

I have a method:

```
function setToMonday( date ) {
    var day = date.getDay() || 7;  
    if( day !== 1 ) 
        date.setHours(-24 * (day - 1)); 
    return date;
}
```

I need to call the `split` method on the returned date. But `split` is not recognised: `gg.split is not a function`

```
var gg =  setToMonday(new Date().toString());
var week1 = gg.split('T')[0];
console.log(week1);
```

I've seen on other Q's to use `toString()`But it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: How does `setToMonday` not throw, when you are calling `date.getDay` on a string? I am confused.

Comment: You should be calling `toString()` on the return of `setToMonday()`, not as the input to `setToMonday()`

Answer (score 3):

You're putting `toString` in the wrong place. You don't want to convert the date you're passing in to a string, you want to convert the date you're getting out to a string:

```js
var gg = setToMonday(new Date());
var week1 = gg.toString().split('T')[0];
console.log(week1);
```